# Office 365: Fetching calendar events throwing error

Tags: office365, office365-restapi

I am using "[Sync Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations#Syncevents)" REST API to get events from a particular calendar between given start and end date time. When following query parameters are sent, getting proper response back with the list of events.

```
Array
(
    [$top] => 50
    [$orderby] => Start
    [startDateTime] => 2016-02-02T00:00:00Z
    [endDateTime] => 2016-09-09T11:31:21Z
)
```

But if the above query params are changed as shown below 'InternalServerError" message is thrown back.

```
Array
(
    [$top] => 50
    [$orderby] => DateTimeLastModified
    [$filter] => DateTimeLastModified ge 2016-03-09T07:12:19Z
    [startDateTime] => 2016-02-02T00:00:00Z
    [endDateTime] => 2016-09-09T11:33:03Z
)
```

Exception:

```
Array
(
    [error] => Array
        (
            [code] => ErrorInternalServerError
            [message] => Object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[Microsoft.Exchange.Entities.DataModel.Items.Item,Microsoft.Exchange.ExchangeSystem.ExDateTime]]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[Microsoft.Exchange.Entities.DataModel.Calendaring.Event,Microsoft.Exchange.ExchangeSystem.ExDateTime]]'.
        )

)
```

Can any one suggest the reason behind this error?

Answer (score 0):

Per the docs, you cannot use the `$filter` parameter with sync.

> You cannot use the $filter, $count, $select, $skip, $top, and $search query parameters.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Is there a way to query the records based on 'ModifiedTime' of event using 'Sync Events' REST API ?

Comment: Adding to this I noticed one more change for Recurring Events. Earlier if any 1 Occurrence is Edited (Not complete series) only that modified event was received when requested through REST API. But now instead of Occurrence I am getting Series Master as response even though I edited only one Occurrence. Was there any changes made recently ?